# Modifying JSON output for for two different functions

Tags: java, json, gson

I have two functions that each take in an array list descriptors. I am trying to print different JSON outputs for each respective function. I am using the Gson library to help me accomplish this task. I use a Client Data model object to help format the JSON correctly. Attached below are the getters and setters for this.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;


public class ClientData {

    @SerializedName("TrialCountryCodes")
    private List<String> trialCountryCodes;

    @SerializedName("CancerGenePanel")
    private String cancerGenePanel;

    public ClientData() {
        this.trialCountryCodes = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    public List<String> getTrialCountryCodes() {
        return trialCountryCodes;
    }

    public void setTrialCountryCodes(List<String> trialCountryCodes) {
        this.trialCountryCodes = trialCountryCodes;
    }

    public String getCancerGenePanel() {
        return cancerGenePanel;
    }

    public void setCancerGenePanel(String cancerGenePanel) {
        this.cancerGenePanel = cancerGenePanel;
    }

}
```

The problem comes in with the Trial Country Codes. When I call one function I want Trial Country Codes  to be visible in the JSON output. When I call the other one I don't want Country Codes to be visible. Attached below are the two functions one takes in one file and the other takes in two files. When the function has one file I don't want Trial Country Codes to be visible. When the function has two files I do want Trial Country Codes to be visible

```
descriptors = HelperMethods.getBreastCarcinomaDescriptorsFromCsvFile("/Users/edgarjohnson/eclipse-workspace/CsvToJson/src/in.csv");

descriptors = HelperMethods.getBreastCarcinomaDescriptorsFromCsvFile("/Users/edgarjohnson/eclipse-workspace/CsvToJson/src/in.csv", "/Users/edgarjohnson/eclipse-workspace/CsvToJson/src/EU.csv");

HelperMethods.writeJsonFile(descriptors, "JsonOutput.json");
```

More BackGround info: I am getting these values from a CSV file in which I read the CSV file and write the JSON output to multiple files. This is the code that I use to format my JSON file:

```
public static List<BreastCarcinomaDescriptor> getBreastCarcinomaDescriptorsFromCsvFile(String fileName, String fileName2) {

        List<BreastCarcinomaDescriptor> descriptorsAndCountrycodes = new ArrayList<BreastCarcinomaDescriptor>();

        BufferedReader bufferedCsvFile = HelperMethods
                .getCsvFileBuffer(fileName);

        BufferedReader bufferedCsvFile2 = HelperMethods
                .getCsvFileBuffer(fileName2);


        List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> line2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        HelperMethods.readCsvToStrings(lines, bufferedCsvFile);
        HelperMethods.readCsvToStrings(line2, bufferedCsvFile2);
        List<String> countryList = new ArrayList<String>();
        System.out.println(line2);
        //populate the country list using file2
        countryList = Arrays.asList(line2.get(0).split(","));
        System.out.println(countryList);

        for (String line : lines) {
            BreastCarcinomaDescriptor descriptor= getBreastCarcinomaDescriptorFromCsvLine(line);
            //enrich this object with country code property
            descriptor.getClientData().setTrialCountryCodes(countryList);
            descriptorsAndCountrycodes.add(descriptor);
        }

        return descriptorsAndCountrycodes;
    }

    private static BreastCarcinomaDescriptor getBreastCarcinomaDescriptorFromCsvLine(String line) {
        BreastCarcinomaDescriptor breastCarcinomaDescriptor = new BreastCarcinomaDescriptor();
        String[] data = line.split(",");

        breastCarcinomaDescriptor.setBatchName(data[0]);
        breastCarcinomaDescriptor.getMetadata().setCharset("utf-8");
        breastCarcinomaDescriptor.getMetadata().setSchemaVersion("1.5");

        if(data.length > 5) {
            breastCarcinomaDescriptor.getSampleInfo().setAge(new Integer(data[5].trim()));          
        }
        breastCarcinomaDescriptor.getSampleInfo().setCancerType(data[3].trim());
        if(data.length>4) {
            breastCarcinomaDescriptor.getSampleInfo().setGender(data[4].trim());
        }

        breastCarcinomaDescriptor.getFiles().add(data[1].concat(".*"));
//      breastCarcinomaDescriptor.getClientData().getTrialCountryCodes().add(descriptorsAndCountrycodes[]);
        //breastCarcinomaDescriptor.getClientData().getTrialCountryCodes().add("20");
        breastCarcinomaDescriptor.getClientData().setCancerGenePanel("");
        breastCarcinomaDescriptor.setCaseName(data[1]);

        return breastCarcinomaDescriptor;
    }
```

What I've Tried: I tried using custom serialization to only display Trial Country Codes  when we take in one file but I am having trouble with this.

Does anyone have any ideas how I can accomplish this task. I feel like the solution is trivial. However, I don't know the Gson Library too well and I am new to java.

How formatted output should look for function that takes in 1 file:

[image: Json output for 1 file]

How formatted output should look for function that takes in 2 files:

[image: Json output for 2 Files]

Answer (score 1):

You can register two different [TypeAdapters](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/TypeAdapter.html) which serialize into the format you want depending on which function gets called. Then each of your functions uses it's own type adapter and can control the details of the transformation.

First function

```
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
builder.registerTypeAdapter(ClientData.class, new ClientDataWithCancerGenePanelAdapter());
Gson gson = builder.create();
```

Second function:

```
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
builder.registerTypeAdapter(ClientData.class, new ClientDataWithTrialCountryCodesAdapter());
Gson gson = builder.create();
```